# How do I make Intellij Idea "Spring Dependencies Diagram" to show only a subset of the beans?

Tags: spring, ide, intellij-idea, dependencies

In Intellij Idea 11.1.2 I have the "Spring Dependencies Diagram", but this shows too much information (there are 100+ beans in the app, with lots of dependencies), I see no clear overview of what is important to me at the moment.

I would like to view only a subset of the beans at a time. I have only one configuration file (the beans are auto-discovered based on their annotations), so filesets wouldn't help me.

The best thing I could come up with was to select some of the interesting beans, then press "show selected nodes with dependencies", but this is very instable, because as soon as I start to rearrange the boxes, they become selected, and the unselected beans disappear.

Is it possible to make "Spring Dependencies Diagram" ignore part of the beans?

EDIT: I am also interested in other spring dependency graph visualisation tools. Does Eclipse or Netbeans have something like this?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, [STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) provides some views to overview the Spring specific project structure, but nothing like the visualisation in IDEA